# pandas to access text file

Tags: python, pandas, google-colaboratory, text-files

I am using pandas to access  a file whose content is as follows:

```
English Word    anger   anticipation    disgust fear    joy negative    positive    sadness surprise    trust   Bengali Word
aback   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   বিস্মিত
abacus  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   অ্যাবাকাস
```

I am trying to read this file in Google colab using the following code.

```
import pandas as pd
cols = ['English Word','anger   ','anticipation ','disgust  ','fear ','joy  ','negative ','positive ','sadness  ','surprise ','trust    ','Bengali Word']
 
data=pd.read_csv('/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Bengali-NRC-EmoLex.txt', sep=' ', header=None, names=cols)
data
```

But my output is not correct. Can you please tell me how can I read the above text file in Python?

Answer (score 0):

I have used separator as Tab. The updated code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
cols = ['English Word','anger','anticipation','disgust','fear','joy','negative','positive','sadness','surprise','trust','Bengali Word']
 
data=pd.read_csv('/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Bengali-NRC-EmoLex.txt', sep="\t", header=None, names=cols)
data
```